# Average pixels in an image (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pixel

I am still a beginner using Matlab and my question is the following:
I have a 240x320 image, I decomposed it into its RGB channels, then, It is correct to add two of the three channels and also average the result of the sum? Should I do this in order to the new resulting image doesn’t show with such high values.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to find the average intensity of each RGB pixel or the average intensity of the entire image?

Comment: Do you expect a result with 240 by 320 average values or just a single value?